# Project Euler - 3 | why program doesn't t exit from the while loop?

Tags: php, html

Hello I'm Andrea and I'm a beginner to programming,

I' m trying to solve the Project Euler - problem 3, but **I can't understand why the "j" doesn't exit from the while loop ( It generates an infinite loop )**.

When the "j" enters in the else (inside the while) the "$prime" variable value is set to true, so I suppose the program has to exit from the while loop (because the second condition: `while ( $j < $i || $prime != true || $noPrime != true )`), but the program continues to go on.

I know the code is not complete for the problem and not beautiful too, but I'm really stuck on this problem.

Code below:

```
<body>
    
<?php
$num = 20;
$z = 0; $j = 2;

$fPrimes = [];

$prime = false;
$noPrime = false;
$primeFactor = 0;

for ($i=2; $i < 20; $i++) { //check for every number under the $num

    echo "<b>My i : " . $i . "</b><br>";

    if ($num % $i == 0) { //check if is a divisor

        $j = 2;
        if ($i == 2)  $j = 1;
       
        while ( $j < $i || $prime != true || $noPrime != true ) { 

            echo "My j : " . $j . "<br>";

            if ($i % $j != 0) { // j is not a divisor

                echo "My j : " . $j . " not a divisor<br>";

            }elseif ($i % $j == 0 && $j != $i && $j != 1) { // j = divisor but not =$i and not =1

                echo $i . " Not f.prime!<br>";

                $noPrime = true;
            }else{ // j is a divisor and prime factor

                echo $i . " It's a f.prime!<br><br>";
                $primeFactor [$z] = $i;

                $prime = true;
                $z++ ;
            }
            if ($prime == false && $noPrime == false) $j++;    
        }

        $prime =  false;  
        $noPrime =  false;
        
    }else echo "<br>" . $i . " Not divisor.</br><br>";
}

for ($i=0; $i < count($primeFactor ) ; $i++)  echo $primeFactor [$i] . " ";

?>

</body>
```

Here below the result:

```
My i : 2
My j : 1
2 It's a f.prime!

My j : 1
2 It's a f.prime!

.. infinite loop

My j : 1
2 It's a f.prime!
```

**Thanks in advance for the help**

Comment: Your Boolean condition is wrong. Use && instead of ||.

Comment: It works now! Thanks a lot! But I don't understand why..?
But Logical operator: 
&& if both conditions are true
|| if one of conditions is true
In my case I need one (true) of the while conditions, so why I' ve to put && instead of || ....?

Comment: Welcome to SO! `$noPrime != true` is a very confusing way to write `$noPrime === false` which is a verbose way of writing `!$noPrime`. You actually do want `&&`, which stops the loop if any of the 3 conditions becomes false. Using `break` or a function lets you avoid these confusing boolean flags--lots of booleans and conditionals increases cyclomatic complexity and makes it hard to reason about what state the program is in at a given point.

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks a lot for the advice, I' ll try to use them the next times

Comment: I'm not sure how else to phrase it. The loop should keep running as long as _all_ of the conditions are true, not _any_ of the conditions are true. In order words, as soon as one condition becomes false, you want to stop the loop. I think simplifying these conditions to be cleaner now would actually make it easier to understand and reduce your confusion. It's easier to reason about "something is false" than "something is not equal to true".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop condition is written listing all the things that must be true in order for it to keep looping. If any one of those becomes false it is done and the condition should evaluate to false.

Using || doesn’t evaluate to false until all 3 things are false. True || false || true is still true so it keeps looping.

Using && evaluates to true if any one of these things is false.

Also be on the lookout for redundancy. The two booleans are two ways of expressing the same thing.

Comment: @ggorlen: you’re right, I had not paid attention to that part of it, thank you for the correction.